# Position images of various size in a grid with CSS

Tags: css, grid, positioning, thumbnails

I have a series of images (about a 100 or so) that have been resized so that they fit in a background box that is 130x130. The images are either 130 wide or 130 high. How do I style the image so that they appear in the middle of the 130px box.

This is the effect I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NcIh.png

Comment: Can you post your code?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm still curious about this question - I really want to know if there's a way to do this semantically (still including the `<img>` tag), and still achieve the desired effect, even if it means adding an extra `<div>` to do so - willing to give the bounty to anyone who can get that effect.

Comment: (Note: The more browser compatibility/semantics, the better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use them as backgrounds for a div, you're all set:

CSS:

```
div.box-images div {
    float: left; /* has them left-align */
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 12px; /* gives them gutters in between */
    background-position: 50% 50%; /* ensures they're centered */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='box-images'>
    <div style='background-image: url(images/sample1.png);'></div>
    <div style='background-image: url(images/sample2.png);'></div>
    [etc.]
    <br style='clear: both;' />
</div>
```

Comment: i agree with most of this except your background position. So much simpler to put `background-position: center center;`. Plus i'd probably put the class in outer element so that i wouldnt have to write it in each image element.

Comment: Yeah, good call on something like ".box-images div". I don't see how typing almost twice as many characters in "center center" is an improvement on "50% 50%", however, but I suppose that's picking nits.

Comment: I wouldnt say its improvement but somehow it just makes more sense to me :D I realized that something important is missing `background-repeat: no-repeat;` or else the shit will hit the fan.

Comment: Yes, good point. I edited the answer to reflect a couple things brought up since I posted it. The general concept still holds, though.

Comment: Visually, tha works, but semantically, it makes no sense. There's no content without the image tags.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method that has two main differences: avoids the use of background images (the use of which is semantically weird as Nightfirecat mentioned) and puts the images within an unordered list. The latter isn't necessary but is arguably follows CSS best practices.

I haven't tested extensively but on recent Firefox, Chrome and IE for PC. I had to add a hack for IE7 based on [this page's suggestions](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html). That's the reason for the empty `<span>` for each list item.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#boxes {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
 }
#boxes li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 30px;
}
#boxes li div {
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block
}
#boxes li div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto
}
</style>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
#boxes li div * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#boxes li div img {
  position: relative;
}
#boxes li div span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="boxes">
  <li><div><span></span><img src="wide1.jpg"></div></li>
  <li><div><span></span><img src="wide2.jpg"></div></li>
  <li><div><span></span><img src="wide3.jpg"></div></li>
  <li><div><span></span><img src="tall1.jpg"></div></li>
  <li><div><span></span><img src="wide4.jpg"></div></li>
  <li><div><span></span><img src="tall2.jpg"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Done quickly, so it's entirely possible that there are some bugs.

Comment: So, without IE7 support, you would just omit the `<span>` from the solution?

Comment: P.S. Why is the `<div>` even in there? Moving all of the `<div>` styles to its containing `<li>` seems to work just fine? http://jsfiddle.net/WK4qG/ (Or is it to fix an IE bug?)

Comment: Yes - both the <div> and <span> are for IE7 formatting. So it can be greatly simplified if you don't feel the need to support IE7. I also just tested it in IE quirks mode which generally corresponds with IE6 and it appears to work in that as well...

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't use background images.

I would, if possible, apply a class to each box that holds these image. the box would have set height and width as you mentioned.

Then, with jQuery or javascript, add a class depending on the images height or width. so if the width is 130px, add the class of top and bottom padding. If the image is 130 high, add the left and right padding class.

Hope this makes sense and helps you. Let me know if you need me to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Although I only tested in fx, chrome and IE9 but you can use `vertical-align: middle` + `line-height: 130px` on the image like this:

css:

```
div.box {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 130px;
}

div.box img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

html

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
</div>
```

I'm getting a little bit of a push though, when the image is the same height as the box. Anyone else know why?  You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9bu5Z/1/